# How to hide the bottom border for an accordion, when the accordion is collapsed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, razor

When the expanded Accordion is collapsed, the bottom border on the expanded accordion is still visible. The bottom border shouldn't be visible when the accordion is collapsed. Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/dcxj4raL/2/

I am not sure if the script is wrong or if it's CSS. Is there a way to hide the border bottom? How can I **fully** collapse the accordion(including the bottom border)?

cshtml:

```
<h2 class="accordion-toggle">Open Collapsible</h2>
<div id="anyId" class="collapse">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<h2 class="accordion-toggle">Open Section 1</h2>
<div class="collapse">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
var collapsible = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-toggle");
        for (var i = 0; i < collapsible.length; i++) {
            collapsible[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                var currentClassList = event.currentTarget.classList;
                if (currentClassList.contains('collapsed')) {
                    event.currentTarget.classList.remove("collapsed");
                    var content = event.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
                    content.style.maxHeight = null;
                } else {
                    for (var j = 0; j < collapsible.length; j++) {
                        collapsible[j].classList.remove("collapsed")
                        collapsible[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
                    }
                    this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
                    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                        content.style.maxHeight = null;
                    } else {
                        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

CSS:

```
.accordion-toggle {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.collapsed, .accordion-toggle:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapse {
 padding: 0 18px;
 max-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
 margin-bottom: -4px;
 border-left: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
 border-right: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with just css by moving the border css from `.collapse` to:

```
.collapsed + .collapse {
  border-left: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-right: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1
}
```

[Editted fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2efgyz4/)

Comment: Hi @Cuong, I have a follow up question, how will the css you mentioned work in an example such as this: https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/dcxj4raL/4/ .

Comment: When your section collapse, it will have class `collapsed` and the selector `.collapsed + .collapse` will find the `.collapse` placed immediately after `.collapsed` . That's why the border only exist when section collapsed.

Comment: But let's say  if I don't have the class 'collapsed' in my new CSS: jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/dcxj4raL/4 . How can I get rid of the bottom border now?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to use js? Did you check my editted fiddle?

Comment: I think my question is, let's say if my code is structured like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/dcxj4raL/6/ . How would I now hide/get rid of the border bottom when the accordion is collapsed?

Comment: The above solution still work. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/6tfqn7kg/

Comment: quick question. Going by your  CSS, I noticed that, when I expanded the accordion, the border color changes to black in the process of expanding before it becomes gray. How can that be fixed to have just gray color throughout expanding?

Comment: You just need to change transition css on `.collapse` to `transition: max-height 1.0s;` then it will be solved.

Comment: Also, I was wondering, When I was collapsing an accordion , I noticed that when the accordions are being collapsed, the borders disappear in that process of being collapsed. Is there a way to show the border as well, when the accordion is collapsed?